# Async Prime Calculation

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following function which calculates the nth prime number (not my function):

```
public long FindPrimeNumber(long n)
            {
                int count = 0;
                long a = 2;
                while (count < n)
                {
                    long b = 2;
                    int prime = 1;// to check if found a prime
                    while (b * b <= a)
                    {
                        if (a % b == 0)
                        {
                            prime = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        b++;
                    }
                    if (prime > 0)
                        count++;
                    a++;
                }
                return (--a);
            }
```

I want to call this function in a wpf application where you enter a number and then the function is invoked with a button:

```
private void one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            answer = FindPrimeNumber(Convert.ToInt64(txtprime.Text));
            MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
        }
```

this works fine but when you start inputting a number from one million this gets slow and blocks the UI.

Therefore, I would like to make the button async so that it does not block the UI.

This is how I tried:

```
 public async Task<long> Async_FindPrimeNumber(long n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        long a = 2;
        while (count < n)
        {
            long b = 2;
            int prime = 1;// to check if found a prime
            while (b * b <= a)
            {
                if (a % b == 0)
                {
                    prime = 0;
                    break;
                }
                b++;
            }
            if (prime > 0)
                count++;
            a++;
        }
        return (--a);
    }
```

The async button:

```
 private async void two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            answer = await Async_FindPrimeNumber(Convert.ToInt64(txtprime.Text));
            MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
        }
```

But the UI is still blocked. How can I make this method async ? 
Thank you

Comment: Your current code is already producing a warning explaining exactly what you're doing wrong, and why your "asynchronous" operation isn't actually asynchronous.

Comment: you need to use a thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make your method async like

```
   private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var answer = await FindPrimeNumberAsync(Convert.ToInt64(txtprime.Text));
        MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
    }

    public  Task<long> FindPrimeNumberAsync(long n)
    {
      return Task.Run<long>(()=>
       {
           int count = 0;
           long a = 2;
           while (count < n)
           {
               long b = 2;
               int prime = 1;// to check if found a prime
               while (b * b <= a)
               {
                   if (a % b == 0)
                   {
                       prime = 0;
                       break;
                   }
                   b++;
               }
               if (prime > 0)
                   count++;
               a++;
           }
           return (--a);
       });
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest it would be better to call the method `FindPrimeNumber` and call that from `Task.Run` inside `button1_Click`, but that's just nitpicking.

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, the compiler will give you a warning telling you exactly what's wrong.

To push CPU-bound work off the UI thread onto the thread pool, you can use `Task.Run`. Note that `Task.Run` should be used to *call* methods, not *implement* them:

```
private async void two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var input = Convert.ToInt64(txtprime.Text);
  answer = await Task.Run(() => FindPrimeNumber(input));
  MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest you can do is to wrap the whole body of the function in `Task.Run`. When entered, the `async` function runs synchronously until the first `await` is reached.

Also, in the event handler, wrap the entire body of that function in `try`-`catch`, `async void` is not capable of propagating exceptions to the caller the way normal synchronous code would.